# Can't find how to make distort effects fit to layer boundaries

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I can't make any of the distort effects to fit my shape layer and is instead using the full size of the comp.

Here is a picture showing the problem:

[image]

I thought that might be coming from my shapes generated from an Illustrator file and created a simple rectangle on a new one, but the problem is still here. I also checked the option we get when clicking the "Toggle Switches / Modes" without any luck either.

I don't remember having this problem before and can't find anything on the web about that.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the problem was the fact I was using a shape layer, tried using an image file and it worked as expected.

Precomposing the shape layer (and making the comp match the layer size) is the easiest workaround, I guess.

Note that the continuously rasterise option will make the effect size match the actual comp size again.